# iOS How to slide in view from bottom, accounting for the navigation bar + status bar height

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, subview, uistatusbar

I'm trying to display a custom view like an action sheet in a `root view controller` within a  `UINavigationController`, but I always end up having the bottom obscured because I don't account for the `UINavigationBar` + `status bar` height.

For example the following code will have 64 points worth of bottom part of `customView` obscured:

```
CGFloat height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    customView.center = CGPointMake(width / 2.0, height - customViewHeight / 2.0);
}];
```

I could just use `setFrame` instead of `center` but that is irrelevant because it will give me the same results more or less.

I know using constants like `-64` pts is not desirable, so is there a away to convert points to the actual screen coordinates? What is the best practice?

**Edit (Possibly an additional question)**

I'm trying to have a view from outside the bottom of the screen slide in like an `UIActionSheet`, and every time I try to do this, I always run into the same problem.

I try to set the initial subview `frame` `origin.y` to the height of the screen, and have the subview animate to `(screenHeight - subviewHeight)`, which is why I always run into my problem of having the bottom 64 CGPoints obscured.

What's the best way to do this kind of implementation? I've tried searching for sample code, but I've only seen codes using height like `CGPoint height = 480.0 - subviewHeight;`, which I heard is poor practice.

Comment: Which `UIView` are you adding your presenting view to?

Comment: It's the initial view controller's view (main screen). The view controller is the root view controller of the `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this

```
@implementation UIView (XXScreenConversions)
- (CGPoint)xx_pointFromScreenPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    CGPoint inWindow = [self.window convertPoint:point fromWindow:nil];
    return [self.window convertPoint:inWindow toView:self];
}

- (CGPoint)xx_screenPointFromPoint:(CGPoint)point {
    CGPoint inWindow = [self.window convertPoint:point fromView:self];
    return [self.window convertPoint:inWindow toWindow:nil];
}
@end
```

Comment: This helps! Thanks! But just for future reference, is this what I have to use all the time when I want to account for the offset for `origin.y`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Adam's response, I don't think you should rely on the screen height in your calculations here either. Because it's likely the superview you are adding your subview too isn't actually full screen, so it's pushing the bottom off.

If you're slinging rects around, you're better off grabbing the `view.bounds` of the view you're adding it too and using that for your frame calculations.

If you're using auto layout (if not, learn it cause it's awesome), use the `topLayoutGuide`.

Comment: I used view.bounds, but it gives the same result. I'll have to look into topLayoutGuide, but I'm not using auto layout.

Comment: It's a little hacky, but you could inset the view.bounds rect with the topLayoutGuide.constant. That's essentially what auto layout does when insetting scrollViews.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing points and pixels. [Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29) is a measure of typography that comes from the days of hot metal typesetting (and it can mean a number of physical measurements). A point in the CGPointMake sense is simply a location on the screen measured in pixels. What you need to be doing is to measure the `height` value more accurately.

You should have a look at [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html) in the Apple "iOS 7 UI Transition Guide" to get a handle on how to use helper views like `topLayoutGuide` in calculating the height of the screen correctly. Very likely you're going to find `topLayoutGuide` takes care of the 64 pixels perfectly, it always has in my experience.

Comment: Yes, I mean point as in CGPoint. I thought using pixels causes more confusion because of retina and non-retina display.

Comment: Mostly you can forget about whether something is a retina display or not! To the developer, a device's native coordinate system is the non-retina dimension and retina just works. You can look at the scale property but often this is just a path to confusion.

Comment: Well, then what's the non-confusing, widely-accepted terminology when you say the navigation bar + status bar height is "64 CGPoints"? (Not too relevant to the question per se, but for future reference)

Comment: CGPoint is a struct containing both x and y values, so it isn't right to talk about 64 of them unless you mean 64 locations in 2D space. When you want to talk about the height of the nav bar + status bar it is just pixels.

Comment: Okay, my bad for saying CGPoints. I meant to say floating-point values. I know you know much more about programming than I do, but I can't take your opinion seriously when I see Apple documentation using the term `points` all the time, while you are saying using points causes confusion. If anything, I think pixels causes more confusion. [View Programming Guide - Points Versus Pixels](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html)

Comment: When you work with designers who talk about font sizes in terms of points it does get very confusing, especially when they specify "24 point" but they mean "24 pixels high from capital to descender", and to get that you need to create a UIFont using [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.f]; Does Apple confuse points and pixels? The usage of CGPoint to mean a point in 2D space is completely consistent with geometric and computer graphics usage in general. UIFont's pointSize property returns a point size and not a height in pixels.

Comment: Good point. However, where in my post am I ever referring to the design or font for you to come to the conclusion that I have the two concepts confused? If you've followed my link, it specifically says "the size of the rectangle is 240 by 380 points", which is basically the same thing when I said "64 points" in my original post. It also says "One point does not necessarily correspond to one pixel on the screen." I can't possibly see why you are so hung up on this pixel term. I appreciate you helping people out, but please don't give unsolicited advice.

Comment: There are not many more explicit ways to solicit advice than by asking a question on a site devoted to questions and answers. I guess I had trouble deciphering your confusion, and came to the wrong conclusion about what you could have meant when using points as a measure of height - as they are in typography. Sorry if that upset you.